# How can I return a list/array/Json object of id's from the controller in the ViewBag and add it to the htmlAttributes of an actionlink?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have an Action which returns a partial view, and I would like to store a list of id's in the `ViewBag.property = ids` (somewhere temporary) and add them to an actionLink into the `object HtmlAttributes`

How can this be done, or is there a better way to do this?

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction() {
    // do something and return a partialview
    List/Array/Dictionary ids;  // ?
    foreach (MyClass c in List<MyClass>) { 
        // Doing something else but need to store the ID somewhere for the ActionLink
        ids[] =c.Id ?
        ids.Add(c.Id) = c.Id; ?
    }
    ViewBag.myProperty = ? //(e.g. some List or Array to Json?)
}
```

In the partialview

```
@Html.ActionLink("action", ..., new { idArray = @ViewBag.myProperty } )
```

Is this possible, or is there a better alternative? Can this be done passing a Json object to the htmlAttributes in an actionLink?

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new    
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(ids);
ViewBag.myProperty = sJSON;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the session (HttpContext.Current.Session) to store a variable like this instead of viewbag.  This way, you would not attach the array to the link, just the session key.

In the code:

`string mylistkey = ?;//choose a meaningful and unique key name`
`HttpContext.Current.Session.add(mylistkey, list); //your list in your example`
`ViewBag.myProperty = mylistkey; // just put the key in the viewbag`

In the pagecode:
`@Html.ActionLink("action", ..., new { idSessionKey = @ViewBag.myProperty } )`

In your target page, you use the key to retrieve the actual array from the session:
`string sessionKey = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[idSessionKey];`
`List<MyClass> mylist=(List<MyClass>)(`
`HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey]);`
`HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(sessionKey);`

There are many other ways to do this, and I think you can make your JSON idea work as well.  This would be my suggestion because it keeps your URL line more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While that is a valid answer, my only issue with the suggestion is that the view/page has many other links in which they can leave the page. If they don't use the links which remove that key from the session then it is left in session. The list can potentially be quite large and we generally try avoid filling up session.

Comment: Hmm, I'll mark this as the answer as this would work, it's just not exactly what I am looking for. If someone posts a working JSON answer I'll update the answer.